# Google Visualization API using Google Spreadsheet as "Authenticated" Data Source via JavaScript Client API Auth

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-drive-api

The Google Visualization API documentation states the easiest way to use a Google Spreadsheet as a Data Source is to publish it. And under normal circumstances that works great. But I am dynamically creating the Google Spreadsheet using the Drive API. So, even when I am authorized, then create a spreadsheet, I cannot immediately use that spreadsheed as a data source. So I need one of two solutions:

1) Programatically "Publish" the Google Spreadsheet via the Drive API?

2) Authenticate the Query to the Google Visualization API?

The code looks like this:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=' + idOfSpreadsheet + '&headers=1&pub=1';
var query = new google.visualization.Query(url);
query.send(drawTable);
```

You would think I could append the auth token to the url varible, but I can't find any documentation on that.  This would be my first choice.

Otherwise, I could publish the spreadsheet but I can't find how to do that from JavaScript. Currently, I have to open the newly created spreadsheet in the Google Drive UI and manually publish it. I step I would not like to have to explain to users how to accomplish with each dynamically created spreadsheet.

Cheers James

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you could try to append the oauth 2 access token to the url.

After creating your google spreadsheet, you can query its metadata by doing an authorized:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<file_key>
```

[See documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).

In the ile's metadata you will get the list of possible export formats:

```
...
"exportLinks": {
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/...&exportFormat=pdf",
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/...exportFormat=ods",
  "application/vnd.ms-excel": "https://docs.google.com/...&exportFormat=xls"
},
...
```

CSV is not listed because it will only allow you to download the first sheet but it is supported so you could use the following URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=<file_key>&exportFormat=csv
```

You have to do an authorized request though so you wil need to append your auth token like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=<file_key>&exportFormat=csv&access_token=<auth_token>
```

Be aware that the OAuth 2.0 access tokens are only valid for 1h so you need to refresh them eventually.